# how to check whether an opencv window already exists or not

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to know whether an opencv window already exists or not. One possible solution is,

```
std::string winName = "winName";
cv::namedWindow(winName);
HWND* hwnd = (HWND*)(cvGetWindowHandle(winName.c_str()));
if(hwnd == nullptr)
{
    std::cout<<"\n window handle hwnd is null \n";
}
else
{
    std::cout<<"\n window handle hwnd is not null \n";
}

cv::destroyAllWindows();
hwnd = (HWND*)(cvGetWindowHandle(winName.c_str()));
if(hwnd == nullptr)
{
    std::cout<<"\n window handle hwnd is null \n";
}
else
{
    std::cout<<"\n window handle hwnd is not null \n";
}
```

But this is not a cross platform solution. Is there any ?

Comment: Did you mean to write `exists` or `exits`?

Comment: Sorry i corrected my mistake. I intended to write exists. @DavidGrayson